# What is a Rainbow Word™?

Tags: word-property

<sub>*In the spirit of the What is a [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion)/[Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463), a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) puzzles.*</sub>

---

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a **Rainbow Word™**. The ones given here are particularly strong examples, to help you out, and while the order of Rainbow Words™ doesn't matter at all for the rule, I put these examples in a special order for you!

Use the examples below to find the rule:

| Rainbow Words ™ | Not Rainbow Words ™ |
| --- | --- |
| SCARED | CALMED |
| ZEBRAS | HORSES |
| SERIAL | KILLER |
| LIVING | UNDEAD |
| CANADA | FRANCE |
| FEMALE | MALE |
| EFFECT | RESULT |
| BOBBLE | BOUNCE |
| CYBORG | PERSON |
| WIGGLE | QUIVER |

And, in CSV form:

```
Rainbow Word™,Not Rainbow Word™
SCARED,CALMED
ZEBRAS,HORSES
SERIAL,KILLER
LIVING,UNDEAD
CANADA,FRANCE
FEMALE,MALE
EFFECT,RESULT
BOBBLE,BOUNCE
CYBORG,PERSON
WIGGLE,QUIVER
```

Each word can be tested for whether it is a Rainbow Word™ without relying on the other words.
These are not the only examples of Rainbow Words™; many more exist.

**What is the special rule these words conform to?**

Hint to start you off:

> I'm a programmer, so a required step should be done the "programmer way."

Another hint (Day 2):

> Lots of references to colors in this puzzle, aren't there? How do computers display colors?

Comment: Does this require in-depth knowledge of programming?

Comment: hahaha "bobble" and "cyborg" :p

Comment: @Sciborg would [knowledge] or [computer-science] be appropriate tags here?

Comment: The solution doesn't require any deep knowledge of computer science at all - there is just one key concept that is generally common knowledge, especially if you've used art software like MS Paint, GIMP, or Photoshop.

Comment: I think I get what the "key concept" is, but still I'm failing to see how to apply that to those words :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the answer is

> If you group a 6-letter Rainbow Word into 3 pairs of letters, convert each letter to A=0, B=1, ..., Z=25 (0-based indexing in the programming world), and concatenate the numbers in each pair, you get a valid RGB color value written in decimal, as in (0, 0, 0) being black and (255, 255, 255) being white. The requirement is that **all three numbers that represent R, G, B respectively must be between 0 and 255 inclusive**.
>
> Example:
> - SCARED = 18 2 0 17 4 3 = (182, 17, 43) (ignore leading zeros) = red color
> - CALMED = 2 0 11 12 4 3 = (20, **1112**, 43) = not a valid color
>
> If you use 1-based indexing instead (so A=1, ..., Z=26), the pattern doesn't work for ZEBRAS.

Proof of Rainbow Words (and why they're in special order):

> SCARED = 18 2 0 17 4 3 = (182, 17, 43) = **red**
> ZEBRAS = 25 4 1 17 0 18 = (254, 117, 18) = **orange**
> SERIAL = 18 4 17 8 0 11 = (184, 178, 11) = dark **yellow** (olive?)
> LIVING = 11 8 21 8 13 6 = (118, 218, 136) = **light green**
> CANADA = 2 0 13 0 3 0 = (20, 130, 30) = **dark green**
> FEMALE = 5 4 12 0 11 4 = (54, 120, 114) = dark **cyan**
> EFFECT = 4 5 5 4 2 19 = (45, 54, 219) = **blue**
> BOBBLE = 1 14 1 1 11 4 = (114, 11, 114) = **violet**
> CYBORG = 2 24 1 14 17 6 = (224, 114, 176) = **pink**
> WIGGLE = 22 8 6 6 11 4 = (228, 66, 114) = **pink-red**
>
> So the colors represented by the words are in the **rainbow order**, or more precisely, in the order of appearance in the **color wheel**! You can check each color by entering the RGB values [on this site](https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/color/rgb-to-hsl.html), and the "hue" value is the position (angle) of that color in the color wheel.

Comment: Yup :) great job!